# I am a recruiter at a company. Can I share candidates that we don't hire with other companies?

Tags: recruitment

I am a salaried recruiter at a US-based 50-person startup. We have been pretty successful recruiting for developer positions here, we have no immediate plans to hire more developers, and we've rejected some pretty great candidates.

Looking around at the tech scene, I know there are other companies that some of these rejected candidates would be a great fit for (I even have friends working at some of these companies).

Can I share these candidates with other companies? How about just a name? What if I email the candidate first and ask him/her for permission to share their info?

Comment: Breach of confidence. That is for starters

Answer (score 12):

> What if I email the candidate first and ask him/her for permission to share their info?

**This.** I would not recommend sharing their info without their consent.

After finding such candidate(s), and rejecting them, you can then ask if they would like you to do such thing (either in a mail, or face to face if it is the case).

You can then proceed to share their contact (or not) with that other company.

As an alternative, **you could share those other job openings with the candidate**, instead of giving the candidate's info to those companies. This way you are also giving that person the chance to apply with their own means and in the moment they want to do so.

Also make sure you aren't going against any policy of the company you work for before doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Ed Heal mentioned that it would be a breach of confidence.

But I wouldn't necessarily go straight to that. At the end of the day, candidates want to find a job, I would have reservations that they would have an issue if a position (that fits) was found through another recruiter. (they win regardless). Think of it like a referral within any profession.

You don't think it would work, but you give them the names of those whom you think will have a role for them to apply for. Let them make the initial contact, don't give the candidates info to another recruiter without consent.

Comment: if I applied at Company A, I would be very unhappy if my information was passed to Company B without my consent and would likely blacklist them both. The UK/EU and Australia have some pretty strict rules on privacy

Comment: The recruiter gives the name of another recruiter to the candidate. The candidate then has the choice of following up with the referral or not.